# Is it a valid likelihood ratio test?

Tags: likelihood-ratio

We know a valid LRT should compare nested models. Suppose there are four models:

```
model1 = gamm4(y ~ x + s(t))
model2 = glmer(y ~ x + t)

model3 = gamm4(y ~ 1 + s(t), random = ~(1|t))
model4 = gam(y ~ x + s(t))
```

I am not sure they are nested model. Can we compare `model1` and `model2`? And can we compare `model3` and `model4`?